# not getting the insert data in mysql using visual basic

Tags: mysql, vb.net

when try to insert a data on my database it always received a null value

here is my code,

```
query = "INSERT INTO tbl_Inventory (Asset_Code,Item_Name,Category,Location,Serial_No,Description,Date_Acquired,Date_Inventory,Remarks,Item_Status)" _
        "VALUES (@assetcode , @itemname , @category, @location, @serialNo, @description, @dateacquired, @dateinventory, @remarks, @itemstatus)"


Dim cmd As New Odbc.OdbcCommand(query, conn)

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@assetcode", varasset)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemname", txtItemName.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@category", txtcategory.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@location", txtLocation.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@serialNo", txtSerialNo.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", txtDescription.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateacquired", txtDateAcquired.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateinventory", txtdateInventory.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@remarks", txtRemarks.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemstatus", cmbstatus.SelectedText)

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: Show `cmd.CommandText` after all parameters insertion.

Comment: What do you mean with _it always received a null value_?

Comment: I'm fairly certain that you cannot use "@" as a parameter prefix for MySQL with ODBC. That's not an official MySQL thing. It's a Microsoft thing that MySQL supports via Connector/Net so as to be as much like `SqlClient` as possible. Unless there's a specific reason that you must use ODBC, don't. Use Connector/Net instead. If you must use ODBC then I think you need to use ":" as a parameter prefix but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: i add this "cmd.CommandText = query" and i still not getting the data i input from the textbox to my database,

Comment: Also it´s not recommended to use `AddWithValue`. Use [Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlParameterCollection_Add_System_String_System_Data_SqlDbType_) instead